# Iphone Development using Data from Wiki using SPARQL

Tags: iphone, wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

I am looking into developing Iphone app that will use Data from wikipedia.  I learned that you can query wiki using sparql end point.  Does any one know any websites that can be used to query such data.  I am trying to use DBPedia but sometimes i get timeout errors.  I am looking for something more stable.  Do you think that it would be very slow if i am getting a large result set?

Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another sparql endpoint that can be used to query DBpedia dataset is [lod.openlinksw.com](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql). It is backed with more servers, but has a lag in updating dataset. Anyways, you need to construct queries that retrieve small result sets to achieve better response time.

Comment: Thanks you for your response!  I am going to be using that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are querying against the [official DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) hosted in Virtuoso ? If so being a community driven and hosted endpoint there are restrictions on use, particularly in terms of the size of the result sets that can be returned which has a restricted 2000 rows to protect it from abuse. Should you want to obtain larger result sets then it is recommended the SPARQL LIMIT and OFFSET clauses be used to retrieve results in chunks of 2000.

If you really want a dedicated DBpedia SPARQL endpoint with no restrictions and under your control, OpenLink Software provide an option to instantiate and host your own [DBpedia EC2 AMI](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtAWSDBpedia351C) in the cloud which is an exact replica of the official DBpedia SPARQL endpoint both hosted in Virtuoso.

Note the [LOD Cloud Cache](http://lod.openlinksw.com) hosted in Virtuoso does also include the DBpedia Datasets from the official DBpedia SPARQL endpoint along with most of the major datasets in the [LOD Cloud](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/lodcloud/state/), and hosted on a larger Virtuoso clustered server allowing a maximum of 100000 rows per query.